# Ограничить количество вводимых данных

Tags: ajax, javascript

Снова всем привет!

Есть у меня в php обработчике, чек формы

```
if(empty($_FILES['file']['name'])) $error .= 'Файл не выбран<br/>';
else if (!in_array($ext, $arr)) $error .= 'Не верный формат<br/>';
if ($_FILES['file']['size'] > 1048576 * 50) $error .= 'Большой размер<br/>';

if($error){
   echo $error;
}
```

И когда ошибки есть они отправляются в ajax скрипт

```
success: function(response){
     $(fileResult.html(response.responseText)).append(response);
}
```

все бы ничего, но если много раз нажать к примеру отправить при пустой форме, появится много строк, к примеру

```
Файл не выбран
Файл не выбран
Файл не выбран
Файл не выбран
Файл не выбран
Файл не выбран
Файл не выбран
```

Как это можно предотвратить ??

Comment: Так может вам проще не отправлять данные, если файл не выбран? Ну, и метод html() - никто не отменял. Используйте его вместо добавления новых сообщений методом append().

Comment: @Deonis спасибо помогло

Comment: @Евгений  Кузнецов, кстати, я что-то не могу въехать в эту строку:

    $(fileResult.html(response.responseText)).append(response);

Может усталость сказывается, но всё же, вы текст ответа добавляете в какой-то элемент, тут же преобразуя всё это в объект jQuery, в который опять же добавляете ответ сервера. Но главное, что оно у вас, как я понимаю, еще и работает, иначе вы бы вопрос задавали в другом направлении ))

Comment: @Deonis спасибо.

А можно как то очистить форму, после успешной отправки ?

<input type="file" name="file" id="file">

Comment: @Евгений  Кузнецов, можно:

    // так
    $('#myform').get(0).reset();
    // или так
    $('#myform')[0].reset();

Comment: @Deonis интересно, благодарю.

и последний вопрос, я наверное уже всем надоел :(

как проверить пуступили ли ошибки из php обработчика или нет


if(response == null){
нет ошибок, из php обработчика
} else {
есть ошибки, и мы их выведем
}

Comment: @Евгений  Кузнецов, отправляйте ответом массив, где первый элемент будет содержать какую-то инфу об ошибках или их отсутствии, а второй элемент - данные, которые вы используете в дальнейшем.

Comment: @Deonis спасибо, получилось :)
upd: не совсем получилось :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> upd: не совсем получилось :(

C вами, как обычно - лимит комментариев )) На сервере как-то так:

```
/* ... */
$error = false;
if($a != $b){
   $error = 'Не катит';
}
$txt = 'Если ошибки не будет, то выведите меня на экран';
exit(json_encode(array('error'=>$error, 'text'=>$txt)));
/* ... */
```

В JS:

```
/* ... */
success: function(response){
    if(response.error){
        alert(response.error); // кричим ошибку
    } else {
        $('selector').html(response.text); // всё гуд, выводим данные
    }
}
/* ... */
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь.

Это еще цветочки, я еще java хочу освоить, а это еще десятки вопросов ))